# How can I verify whether or not any sites are using a specific open source HTML element?

Tags: html, calculator

**I want to count how many sites are using this specific HTML calculator as an iframe on their site (for example: 2,798 sites are using this HTML calculator as an iframe on their site.**

The element is a specific calculator written in HTML and can be embedded as an iframe on websites.  Edit: It has "src" and "href" lines, both of which refer to the original (host) site.

Can I quantify how many sites have embedded this element as an iframe, and if so, how?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. What calculator? What code? HTML is already open-source, otherwise we wouldn't be able to use it as web developers. Please clarify your question.

Comment: If the code makes no external requests, then the answer is *you cannot*.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly about specific calculator. But if you are trying to find out specific site linked in other site then you can do that with site linking in. There are lots of sites provide backlink calculator. And if you are finding specific technology used by specific site, then you can do that with the tools like "Wappalyzer". Hope this answer will help you.